# What is the correct expression "it is up to you" vs "that is up to you"?

Tags: grammar

> 1. That is up to you to quit smoking
> 2. Again, that is up to you to know your man and find out what relaxes him

Are these sentences grammatically wrong?

I think "that" in each sentence should be changed to "it" to make the sentences grammatical.

> 3. It is up to you to quit smoking
> 4. Again, it is up to you to know your man and find out what relaxes him

But I have seen 1 and 2 sentences quite often used by native speakers.

Perhaps, is "to quit smoking" and "to know your man and find out what relaxes him" modifying "that" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would change both sentences from "that" to "it." **[It's up to you](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/up-to-someone)** has two definitions: the first that something is someone's *decision*, and the second that something is someone's *responsibility*.

> It's up to you whether we get chicken or steak. (decision)
>
> It's up to you to order the food. (responsibility)

If *up to somebody* is followed by an infinitive, it indicates responsibility.

*That's up to you* is usually used for decision, not responsibility. So in sentences with an infinitive structure after *up to you* (like both of your examples), I would expect *it* and not *that*.

Comment: What about this sentence? "That is up to you to decide". In this case, is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say the use of *that* is necessarily *ungrammatical* (at least not in context) in these sentences, but it's certainly strange and unidiomatic (especially barring that missing context). I can't imagine anybody not wanting to change *that* to *it*.

Comment: I agree with Jason Bassford that it's not necessarily ungrammatical, but it's not preferable. The sentence "That is up to you to decide" is grammatically fine. I'd expect it to come after a question, where "that" refers to the whole question. The "to decide" isn't a necessary component either, because decision is implicit in the "that's up to you" construction. "Is she guilty or innocent? That is up to you [to decide]."